# Reverse Windows + D hotkey

Tags: windows, windows-10, hotkeys

If I use the Windows + D hotkey to go to my desktop is there a way to reopen the programs I had open in the same order as they were?

So if I open Word, Chrome, Excel then press Windows+D the all 3 open again and the Excel screen is on top then Chrome and then Word.

I use windows 10

Comment: Repeating Winkey-D seems to restore all windows, but (at least on Windows 7) does not appear to guarantee the same order/layering.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin it just randomly opens windows.
I work on 2 screens and the windows all open on my main window, also the ones that were open on my second window

Comment: I didn't see the switching-screen on Win7; the layering, however, does not appear to be preserved. I don't have access to a Win10 box with dual screens.

Comment: Nothing random whatsoever with 3 screens and 15 windows on Win 10 here. Only Outlook stays closed because it hides in the tray.

Comment: @DanielB i have MySQL on my left screen and after pressing windows + d twice it opens on my right screen